# Loop Through all tiles on the start screen

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, windows-8.1

Context: Using USMT to setup default tile layout on a windows 8.1 build. IE sites do not show Favicon. Would like to loop through all Pinned tiles on start menu and update so favicon shows.

I can find lots of information on creating a live tile using wpf but nothing for winforms and accessing existing tiles. Looking for any resource.

Note: I do not have code as I am unable to locate any information.

If you down vote then leave a reason - this is a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS changed access to the tiles in 8.1 and this is not feasible.